# Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find erubi-1.7.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, docker-compose, bcrypt-ruby, erubis

Hello i have a problem with bundle.

I am actually developing a rails app in a docker (dockerized rails)

I need to add the bcrypt gem, but when i add this gem and run bundle install ans bundle update i got this error message :

**Thanks for help**

```
web_1  | bundler: failed to load command: rails (/usr/local/bundle/bin/rails)
web_1  | Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find erubi-1.7.0 in any of the sources
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:218:in `specs_for'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:207:in `requested_specs'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in `block in definition_method'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in `setup'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

**Here is my Gemfile :**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
#gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'
gem 'erubi', '~> 1.7'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**And my bundle env**

### Environment

`Bundler       1.16.0.pre.3
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby          2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path   /usr/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /etc
RubyGems      2.6.13
  Gem Home    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  Gem Path    /home/ervin/.gem/ruby/2.4.0:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  User Path   /home/ervin/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  Bin Dir     /usr/bin
Tools

  Git         2.14.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      not installed`

### Bundler Build Metadata

`Built At          2017-10-05
Git SHA           d94616dd8
Released Version  true`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a typo. Pretty sure you need `gem 'erubis', '~> 1.7'`. I can't find reference to a gem called erubi anywhere, so bundler probably can't either.

Comment: Hello thanks you but still an error :

The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Could not find gem 'erubis (~> 1.7)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Comment: Try removing the version, so just `gem 'erubis'`. Bundler will sort out the dependencies and grab whatever version is compatible.

Comment: Still same error message as before
Could not find erubi-1.7.0 in any sources

When I have run bundle install with gem 'erubis'
The output of bundle install is :
Using erubi 1.7.0

Comment: `erubis`, not `erubi`